# Get text from different layout in tablayout fragment

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have three fragments in tab layout. All I want to do is get the content of fragment A in fragment C. I'm using `getLayoutInflater()` to inflate a layout(includes my edit text which I want to get the value of) but I'm getting an empty value in a toast message. This is how I'm trying to implement my work:

```
inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, null);
EditText text= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.someTextID);
String someText= text.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), someText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Also, I wanted to ask if can `<include />` be useful in for the kind of work I want to do?

Provide me a better solution.

Comment: Have you set any text to edit text ? Have you enter any text in edittext ? If not then it will give you blank(empty) value.

Comment: Yes, I have a date in the edit text.

Comment: If you using `View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, null);` in fragment then you'r wrong. Just find id of edittext in `onCreateView()` method of fragment.

Comment: I have that edit text in a different layout. If I do what you're asking it will result in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

After Spending some of my useful time I came to a solution by myself by creating a simple POJO class to set and get my edittext string. I set the edit text value to a variable and set it on my fragment A and then get it on my fragment C. This returned me what I wanted but still if there's any other solution to this it will be much appreciated.